# ReactJS | Failed Prop-Type Expected String got Object instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select, react-proptypes, formik

I am using React-Select, in my form with Formik. I have the following array of Objects, that comes from the API, and which I map through it, in order to transform the data in the format `React-select` wants.

Here is the mapped through array of data, that I supply to the select.

```
[ { "label": "picard", "value": "picard" }, { "label": "riker", "value": "riker" } ]
```

It has a `label` and `value` pair. Exactly like react-select want it to. But in my Formik HOC, I have the PropType for the values of the data property(e.g: groups), to be a string, as it should, since the server will give me and receive  unique strings.

Here is the PropType:

```
      values: PropTypes.shape({
        useraname: PropTypes.string,
        email: PropTypes.string,
        password: PropTypes.string,
        confirmPassword: PropTypes.string,
        group: PropTypes.string
      }),
```

For that reason, every time i try to select an item from the dropdown, I get this:

```
checkPropTypes.js:19 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `values.group` of type `object` supplied to `AddEditUser`, expected `string`.
```

Here is the select element, and the mapping function:

```
  mapListGroupToSelect = () => {
    const { groups } = this.state;
    return groups.map(group => ({
      label: group.name,
      value: group.name
    }));
  };

  const groups = this.mapListGroupToSelect();

  return (
          <div className="pt-2">
            <label className="font-weight-bold">
              Select Group <Asterisk />
            </label>
            <Select
              placeholder="Select a Group (Just One)"
              onChangeCallback={handleChange}
              type="simpleSelect"
              options={groups}
              isMulti={false}
              id="group"
              onChange={options => setFieldValue('group', options)}
            />
            {JSON.stringify(groups, null, 2)}
            <ErrorMessage name="group" component="div" className="text-danger" />
          </div>
)
```

Do you have any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: FYI, `JSON.Stringify` on the groups doesn't work. It throws an error about unexpected props to the react-select.

Comment: Who is defining the values proptype - you, or third-party code? I don't see anywhere you are passing in `values` so I'm assuming it's from react select?

Comment: The values are passed by `react-select` to the Formik HOC... The problem is react select needs an object to work and the `API` and `Formik` needs a string... So I am asking how to make those 2 conditions work together...